# CSS Grid items not fully covering div

Tags: css, css-grid

I have created a grid using CSS grid over an image which is working as expected. However, the grid is showing pixel gaps between the sections at different screen sizes. The gaps seem to appear in different places depending on the screen size.

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

Does anybody have any ideas why this is happening? I'm sure it's a quick fix, but can't for the life of me work it out.

I've included my current code below, but i've also added it here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xyqZym.

```css
.what-we-offer-left-content {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.what-we-offer-main-image {
  z-index: 5 !important;
  max-height: 735px;
}

.what-we-offer-main-image img {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5 !important;
}

.what-we-offer-left-grid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.what-we-offer-grid-container {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
}

.what-we-offer-left-item1,
.what-we-offer-left-item2,
.what-we-offer-left-item3,
.what-we-offer-left-item4,
.what-we-offer-left-item5,
.what-we-offer-left-item6 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1 !important;
}

.what-we-offer-left-item1 {
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient( bottom left, farthest-side, rgba(53, 52, 53, 0.4), transparent), -webkit-radial-gradient(bottom right, farthest-corner, rgba(121, 122, 118, 0.4), transparent 400px);
  background: -o-radial-gradient( bottom left, farthest-side, rgba(53, 52, 53, 0.4), transparent), -o-radial-gradient(bottom right, farthest-corner, rgba(121, 122, 118, 0.4), transparent 400px);
  background: radial-gradient( farthest-side at bottom left, rgba(53, 52, 53, 0.4), transparent), radial-gradient(farthest-corner at bottom right, rgba(121, 122, 118, 0.4), transparent 400px); //box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.what-we-offer-left-item2 {
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient( top left, farthest-side, rgba(53, 52, 53, 0.3), transparent), -webkit-radial-gradient( top right, farthest-corner, rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.3), transparent 300px);
  background: -o-radial-gradient( top left, farthest-side, rgba(53, 52, 53, 0.3), transparent), -o-radial-gradient( top right, farthest-corner, rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.3), transparent 300px);
  background: radial-gradient( farthest-side at top left, rgba(53, 52, 53, 0.3), transparent), radial-gradient( farthest-corner at top right, rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.3), transparent 300px);
}

.what-we-offer-left-item3 {
  background: lightblue;
}

.what-we-offer-left-item4 {
  background: lightpink;
}

.what-we-offer-left-item5 {
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient( top left, farthest-side, rgba(53, 52, 53, 0.2), transparent), -webkit-radial-gradient( top right, farthest-corner, rgba(184, 185, 181, 0.2), transparent 300px);
  background: -o-radial-gradient( top left, farthest-side, rgba(53, 52, 53, 0.2), transparent), -o-radial-gradient( top right, farthest-corner, rgba(184, 185, 181, 0.2), transparent 300px);
  background: radial-gradient( farthest-side at top left, rgba(53, 52, 53, 0.2), transparent), radial-gradient( farthest-corner at top right, rgba(184, 185, 181, 0.2), transparent 300px);
}

.what-we-offer-left-item6 {
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient( top left, farthest-side, rgba(218, 218, 216, 0.2), transparent), -webkit-radial-gradient( top right, farthest-corner, rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.2), transparent 300px);
  background: -o-radial-gradient( top left, farthest-side, rgba(218, 218, 216, 0.2), transparent), -o-radial-gradient( top right, farthest-corner, rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.2), transparent 300px);
  background: radial-gradient( farthest-side at top left, rgba(218, 218, 216, 0.2), transparent), radial-gradient( farthest-corner at top right, rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.2), transparent 300px);
}

.what-we-offer-left-item1::before,
.what-we-offer-left-item2::before,
.what-we-offer-left-item3::before,
.what-we-offer-left-item4::before,
.what-we-offer-left-item5::before,
.what-we-offer-left-item6::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.what-we-offer-left-item1 .what-we-offer-content,
.what-we-offer-left-item2 .what-we-offer-content,
.what-we-offer-left-item3 .what-we-offer-content,
.what-we-offer-left-item4 .what-we-offer-content,
.what-we-offer-left-item5 .what-we-offer-content,
.what-we-offer-left-item6 .what-we-offer-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="what-we-offer-left-content">
  <div class="what-we-offer-left-grid">
    <div class="what-we-offer-content">
      <div class="what-we-offer-grid-container">
        <div class="what-we-offer-left-item1"></div>
        <div class="what-we-offer-left-item2"></div>
        <div class="what-we-offer-left-item3"></div>
        <div class="what-we-offer-left-item4"></div>
        <div class="what-we-offer-left-item5"></div>
        <div class="what-we-offer-left-item6"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="what-we-offer-main-image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536147116438-62679a5e01f2?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e8edad632cfc0900a6af587857693465&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can get rid of float and position that using grid as well. Also, you're probably running into default margins/padding. Are you using reset or normalize or similar?

Comment: what about flexbox? you could use flex and justify-content

Comment: No gaps visible for me. Everything seems to be working as intended. Latest Firefox, Windows 8.1.

Comment: @Mrchief I'm using float as this will be positioned next to another grid on the right side of it and separating them with float. No i'm not using any of those, i'll have a play and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @andrewgi I wanted the grid to scale as squares and was having more success with grid layout. If I can't work this out, I might explore flexbox again.

Comment: @connexo interesting. I've just checked and you're right it does look as expected in firefox. Any ideas why I would be getting the issue in Chrome. Are you able to see the screenshots in the original post?

Comment: What I was getting at is mixing floats and grids is not a good idea. Use flex in conjunction with grid and that is actually better than just using grid.

Comment: No gaps in latest Chrome either. All perfect.

Comment: @connexo that's odd i'm still getting gaps in the latest Chrome over here.

Comment: @Mrchief ah I see so set the two parent divs to display: flex and then use justify? Would this affect the gaps in the grid that i'm experiencing?

Comment: That could help. I use grid for laying out things, and use flex for stacking things (horz/vert). Flexbox and grid use compatible layout methods. Mixing floats, position absolutes creates issues as they are different layout models. Not saying they cannot be used ever, just that it makes things very complicated.

Comment: @Mrchief ok thanks for the advice i'll try reworking it and see if fixes the issue

Comment: CSS Grid is kinda like position absolute on steroids. Your divs don't even have to be nested in HTML or anything semantic. I can position them wherever I want using grids. It's scary powerful!

Comment: @connexo having explored this a bit more if looks like it might be caused by how Chrome is rendering the gradient backgrounds. The below seems to have fixed it. 

 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;